# How to Get Params from Http Post and Insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to capture user entered credentials and use them as a parameter to query a database. Unfortunately, I am a little lost on how to code that process. I am using angular,express, node, jQuery, and html. I am not very experienced with angular, node, and jQuery, so forgive me if this is something very simple; I am here to learn.

Here is the html where the forms live:

```
<!DOCTYPE html > 
<html ng-app="token">
<%include header%>
<%include navbar%>
<div ng-controller="TokenCtrl">
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
<div class="form-group">
<label>email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="loginForm.email" required="required" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginForm.password" required="required" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="handleLoginBtnClick()">Sign in</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the JS for the TokenCtrl and token module, which is a derivative of ng-token-auth:

```
 var a = angular.module('token', ['ng-token-auth']);
 a.config(function($authProvider) {
// the following shows the default values. values passed to this method
// will extend the defaults using angular.extend

$authProvider.configure({
  apiUrl:                  '/users',
  tokenValidationPath:     '/auth/validate_token',
  signOutUrl:              '/auth/sign_out',
  emailRegistrationPath:   '/auth',
  accountUpdatePath:       '/auth',
  accountDeletePath:       '/auth',
  confirmationSuccessUrl:  window.location.href,
  passwordResetPath:       '/auth/password',
  passwordUpdatePath:      '/auth/password',
  passwordResetSuccessUrl: window.location.href,
  emailSignInPath:         '/auth/sign_in/:email/:password',
  storage:                 'cookies',
  forceValidateToken:      false,
  validateOnPageLoad:      true,
  proxyIf:                 function() { return false; },
  proxyUrl:                '/proxy',
  omniauthWindowType:      'sameWindow',
  tokenFormat: {
    "access-token": "{{ token }}",
    "token-type":   "Bearer",
    "client":       "{{ clientId }}",
    "expiry":       "{{ expiry }}",
    "uid":          "{{ uid }}"
  },
  cookieOps: {
    path: "/",
    expires: 9999,
    expirationUnit: 'days',
    secure: false,
    domain: 'domain.com'
  },
  createPopup: function(url) {
    return window.open(url, '_blank', 'closebuttoncaption=Cancel');
  },
  parseExpiry: function(headers) {
    // convert from UTC ruby (seconds) to UTC js (milliseconds)
    return (parseInt(headers['expiry']) * 1000) || null;
  },
  handleLoginResponse: function(response) {
    return response.data;
  },
  handleAccountUpdateResponse: function(response) {
    return response.data;
  },
  handleTokenValidationResponse: function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
});
 });
  a.controller('TokenCtrl', function($scope, $auth) { 
  $scope.handleRegBtnClick = function() {
  $auth.submitRegistration($scope.registrationForm)
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success response
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle error response
    });
};
 $scope.handlePwdResetBtnClick = function() {
  $auth.requestPasswordReset($scope.pwdResetForm)
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success response
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle error response
    });
};
 $scope.handleLoginBtnClick = function() {
  $auth.submitLogin($scope.loginForm)
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success response
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle error response
    });
};
$scope.handleSignOutBtnClick = function() {
  $auth.signOut()
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success response
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle error response
    });
};
});
```

On the run of this function, it leads to this url:

```
'/auth/sign_in/:email/:password'
```

Using Express, I route this url to another function. Here is the route code:

```
app.post('/users/auth/sign_in/:email/:password', routes.verifyusers);
```

Which leads to,

```
exports.verifyusers= function(req, res) {
models.user.find({
where: {
  email: req.params.email,
  password: req.params.password
}
 }).then(function(user) {
    if(user) {
        console.log("alright !")
    };
});
};
```

When the code runs, this is what I get in the console:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "email", "password",    "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."email" =   ':email' AND "user"."password" = ':password' LIMIT 1;
:email
:password
```

This is result is irrespective to the form data.

Comment: What problem do you have with the code you posted? I not sure to get what your question is... As a side note, you should hash your password before sending it to a database.

Comment: Please see update, sorry. When I run the code, I do not capture and insert the form data -- I only get results based off the url, which is :email and :password

Comment: I don't know want $auth.submitLogin is doing but it seems to call the url exatly like "/users/auth/sign_in/:email/:password"

Comment: Yes, precisely. I am lost as to how to insert the form data into the url as a parameter, like so.

Comment: sorry the previous message went to fast, I wanted to ask what is $auth.submitLogin doing ? also did you checked in "req.query" ?

Comment: I just thought, since it's authentication, it is probably sent in the body, you should check here, also if it's the case "/:email/:password" in the url is not usefull

Comment: It is submitting the log in form and sending to a path, which the path is the url

Comment: I've updated the question to include the code for the module token and all of the TokenCtrl

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from `emailSignInPath: '/auth/sign_in/:email/:password',`

You should try with

```
// config
emailSignInPath: '/auth/sign_in'

// route declaration
app.post('/users/auth/sign_in', routes.verifyusers);

// route action
exports.verifyusers = function(req, res) {
  models.user.find({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }
  }).then(function(user) {
    if(user) {
      console.log("alright !")
    };
  });
};
```

ps: don't forget to declare a body parser in your app `app.use(express.bodyParser())`

Comment: The result of this is:    `Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "email", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."email" = NULL AND "user"."password" = NULL LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I edited to mention the bodyparser did you have a middleware for that ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Although, I think the issue here is having no data for the parameter, which we need to get from the form.

Comment: you should check in the network tab of you browser how if the credentials are sent, and how (body, querystring, path?)

Comment: Yes, they as parameters in JSON. but, I do not know how to grab this and use it